# How to create Layout with UIImageView and UICollectionView and collection view changes height on scroll?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

[image]

I would like to create such a layout where on scroll the imageview hides and collection view takes whole screen. I tried this but it doesnt seem to work. I am getting the image view correctly but the collection view has gone dark completely on run. I have a content view(UIView) and scroll View underneath. Thank you

EDIT 1 :- The Cells are not getting displayed. But the collection view is displayed in the layout. How to solve this?

EDIT 2 :- Instead of using the collection view directly I used a container view and embedded my collection view in it and it Worked! However I am still trying to figure out how do i scroll the container view to top when i scroll, i.e. push the image view on the back of container view while it takes the full height of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay So I figured it out.

1. Wreck all of the above. (Though the container view solution is pretty good)
2. Build a collection View controller from scratch having 2 headers, one is the standard and the other one for the image view.
3. Make your view controller a delegate of the collection view flow layout delegate and implement function for referenceSizeForHeaderInSection
4. Do not forget to register for the xib yo have created for the image view header by using registerNib forSupplementaryViewOfKind function of collection view object.